# Instagram Scraping: How would I save stories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I'm am currently coding an Instagram story scraper for fun because why not and I've gotten to the point where I need to download the story files but the sources to the images / videos aren't in the HTML code. Is there a process I can use to get the images to load into the browser's urls? Or is there some other more efficient way of doing this?

I've tried finding the source of the images but they don't exist since its loaded outside of the HTML.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import time

story_page = "https://www.instagram.com/stories" + "/" + account_purging

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# Login
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(myusername)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(mypassword)
time.sleep(2)
# Click Login
try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button/div").click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[5]/button").click()

time.sleep(2)

# Go To stories

driver.get(story_page)
time.sleep(1)


#Download stories seen
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/span/section/div/div/section/div[2]/div[4]")
src = img.get_attribute('src')
print(src)
```

The code returns as None since there isn't a source link directly in plain sight. Using the NETWORK button in source editor I'm able to find it manually but I know there's a more efficient way.

Edit:
Here is an example of a story url. Maybe there's a way using this?

`https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b83f011616e4bb20c52cbc21ca17213f/5CA3832C/t50.12441-16/56522959_2235298350017959_2397626998618515587_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com`

Comment: Put a sample story url

Comment: https://scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b83f011616e4bb20c52cbc21ca17213f/5CA3832C/t50.12441-16/56522959_2235298350017959_2397626998618515587_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-ort2-1.cdninstagram.com